# ion-list is not scrolling and items are not clickable

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3, ion-list

ion-list is is not scrolling and items are not clickable although the item is clickable in another list 
if you would like to help me here is the html code and the code is on github https://github.com/IslamAssem/sidalitac

```
<ion-content class="page-products"  (ionScroll)="onScroll($event)">

  <ion-list  class="list-view" *ngIf="productView=='list'">
    <span *ngFor="let p of products">
      <product [data]="p" [type]="'list'"></product>
    </span>
  </ion-list>


<ion-grid *ngIf="productView=='grid'">
  <ion-col *ngFor="let p of products" col-6>
    <product [data]="p" [type]="'normal'"></product>
  </ion-col>

  <ion-col *ngIf="products.length==0 && !httpRunning" col-12 class="animated fadeIn">
    <h6 text-center>{{'No Products Found!'|translate}}</h6>
  </ion-col>
</ion-grid>

<ion-infinite-scroll #infinite (ionInfinite)="getProducts($event)">
  <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Comment: Link to the github repo is dead. It might be easier to help you, if you reproduce your issue on https://stackblitz.com/